# How to debug / mitigate uncatchable exceptions

Tags: c#, c++, native-code, unhandled-exception

So, for a project I have to use the notoriously error prone GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/) library written in unmanaged C++ (actually I'm using the C# bindings). The problem is sometimes the library bombs and crashes the vhost32.exe process. There is nothing I can do about that. Empty catch blocks won't do me no good, the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException isn't even raised.

The exception thrown is

> Unhandled exception at 0x77B9AA3C (ntdll.dll) in RASTER.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77BAFE38).

So obviously this exception is unrecoverable and Windows shuts down my process. So far so good. Now the problem is, where to I go from here? I don't want the whole process to be killed just because a call to a buggy library fails. What are my options? Spawning a second process and using named pipes for inter-process communication? That would still mean that the *other* process crashes with that "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..." popup. Not good. Unfortunately, for the functionality I need there is no alternative to that library.

```
<gcConcurrent enabled="false" />
<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
```

in my App.config doesn't change a thing. Neither does decorating the method that bombs with the `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` attribute.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Can you catch this failure with SetUnhandledExceptionFilter in a native process? If yes, use two processes solution.

Comment: the problem is my C++ skills are .. well .. not existent ...

Comment: Look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154686/SetUnhandledExceptionFilter-and-the-C-C-Runtime-Li First two code fragments are what you need for the test. Replace `*p = 5;` with GDAL call that crashes the process. Add `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0);` to `OurCrashHandler` If program exits without any Windows messages, you can use two processes solution. Second process must be native C++ process, so you need to know C++ to do this...

Comment: Is it a cross heap issue?  Are your runtimes correct?  What function throws the exception?